# How to select different values from two columns through Select By Attributes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3, select-by-attribute

I'm using ArcMap 10.3. I'm trying to select by attributes different values from two columns.

I want to define the areas where

1. Main rock is GRAVEL And
2. Sub-rocks are :

a. mudstone tephra loess

b- sand mud

c- ...

d- ...

e- sand mud peat

I have tried to do it as shown below

```
"MAIN_ROCK" = 'gravel'  AND "SUB_ROCKS" = 'sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite' AND "SUB_ROCKS" = 'mudstone tephra loess'  AND "SUB_ROCKS"= 'sandstone mudstone tephra silt lignite' AND "SUB_ROCKS" = 'sand mud peat' AND "SUB_ROCKS" ='sand mud'
```

[image]

After I clicked on apply, nothing was highlighted.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is always better to include the text from your Select By Attributes dialog and error message rather than pictures to aid future searches by people who may encounter the same problem but from your picture it looks like changing:

```
"SUB_ROCKS" 'sand mud'
```

to:

```
"SUB_ROCKS" = 'sand mud'
```

should address this instance of the error message you see.

Your second issue of nothing being highlighted after correcting the above should be addressed by improved logic where the elegant suggestion of @FaridCher looks right to me:

```
"MAIN_ROCK"='gravel' AND "SUB_ROCKS" in ('mudstone tephra loess','sand mud','sand mud peat','sandstone mudstone tephra silt lignite','sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite')
```

Comment: I would mention here the *in* operator... SUB_ROCKS in ('sand mud peat','other') is the same as writing SUB_ROCKS = 'sand mud peat' OR SUB_ROCKS = 'other'.. it doesn't make a difference to your selection but the text is much shorter and easier to debug.

Comment: Michael suggestion is right. But **In** operator is for OR conditions and not AND.

Comment: building on top of Polygeo answer, you should use OR instead of AND for SUB-Rock conditions, because a subrock can not be all of the types you have included in your query

Comment: @PolyGeo
Thank you. I will do this in the future. I followed you suggestion but it didn't work

Comment: SO the nice and proper query would be: "MAIN_ROCK"='gravel" 
AND
"SUB_ROCKS" in ('mudstone tephra loess','sand mud','sand mud peat','sandstone mudstone tephra silt lignite','sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite')

Comment: @aelwan I recommend using the [edit] button to do it now while people are trying to help you.  Also, simply saying "it didn't work" is rarely helpful - in what way did it not work?

Comment: @FaridCher

Thanks. I have tried using your query "MAIN_ROCK"='gravel" AND "SUB_ROCKS" IN ('mudstone tephra loess','sand mud','sand mud peat','sandstone mudstone tephra silt lignite','sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite') but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: there is typo change "MAIN_ROCK"='gravel" to "MAIN_ROCK"='gravel'

Comment: Thanks to your help, these queries worked
"MAIN_ROCK" = 'gravel'  AND "SUB_ROCKS" = 'sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite' OR "SUB_ROCKS" = 'mudstone tephra loess'  OR "SUB_ROCKS"= 'sandstone mudstone tephra silt lignite' OR "SUB_ROCKS" = 'sand mud peat' OR "SUB_ROCKS" ='sand mud'  

Another query

"MAIN_ROCK" = 'gravel'  AND "SUB_ROCKS" IN ('sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite', 'mudstone tephra loess', 'sandstone mudstone tephra silt lignite','sand mud peat','sand mud')